# SCSS nesting: child class can't be detected/doesn't work

Tags: sass, quasar-framework

I am new to scss and I cant figure out where my code went wrong. Somehow it can't detect the child of my nested scss. But if I put it out of the parent class the code works well. I am also using quasar framework.

This is my SCSS:

```
.header {
    background: #EFEEF2;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: right;

    .menu-icon { // my code only detects up to here
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-right: 30px;    

        .q-icon:before { // code doesn't detect this either
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    }

    .floating-menu {
        background: white;
        border-radius:10px;
        box-shadow:5px 10px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);

        .text-account {
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #333C52;
        }
    
        .text-profile-logout {
            color: #333C52;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry I'm not very good in explaining in english so I recreated my code [here](https://codepen.io/les_/pen/eYREwBX)

Comment: If you inspect your code you will see that the the `.q-icon` class it applied on the same element as `.menu-icon` so the nesting won't do anything here. The `.floating-menu` class doesn't seem to be applied anywhere (and the menu is outside of the header in the DOM anyway).

Comment: @Arkellys I have my floating-menu class applied to my q-menu element under q-icon

Comment: Yes but it's nowhere in the DOM. You should inspect your code when you have problem like this. Also check this: https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/4553

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by controlling scope. This is the article I based on: [Using Sass to Control Scope With BEM Naming](https://css-tricks.com/using-sass-control-scope-bem-naming/)

my final code:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({})

app.use(Quasar, { config: {} })
app.mount('#q-app')

new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data () {
    return {
     hover:false
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.header{
    background: #EFEEF2;
    height: 51.48px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: right;
    
    &__menu-icon{
        color: #A7A7A7;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-right: 30px;    

    }
  &__floating-menu{
        background: red;
        border-radius:10px;
        box-shadow:5px 10px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);

        .text-account{
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #333C52;
        }
        
        .text-profile-logout{
            color: #333C52;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    }
    
  }
```

```html
<div id="q-app">
      <div class="q-gutter-md" style="max-width: 500px">
        <div class="q-gutter-md header">
          
         <q-icon  
                 flat
                 @mouseover="hover = true" 
                 name="menu" class="header__menu-icon">
         <q-menu 
                 v-model="hover"
                 @mouseleave="hover = false"
                 class="header__floating-menu" auto-close>
             <q-item>
              <q-item-section class="text-account">Account</q-item-section>
            </q-item>

            <q-list style="min-width: 150px">
              <q-item clickable>
                <q-item-section class="text-profile-logout">My Profile</q-item-section>
              </q-item>
              <q-item clickable>
                <q-item-section class="text-profile-logout">Logout</q-item-section>
              </q-item>
            </q-list>
          </q-menu>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```